# Use xmlstarlet to select nodes that do NOT contain a specific subnode

Tags: xmlstarlet

I have thousands of records similar to the one below

```
<holding>
  <holding_id>2225031160001858</holding_id>
  <record>
    <leader>00210cx a22200085 454500</leader>
    <controlfield tag="001">h38165-01alliance_ohsu</controlfield>
    <controlfield tag="004">b10145746-01alliance_ohsu</controlfield>
    <controlfield tag="005">20200417125900.0</controlfield>
    <controlfield tag="008">2004170u\\\\0\\\0001aaund0999999</controlfield>
    <datafield ind1="2" ind2=" " tag="852">
      <subfield code="b">OHSUMAIN</subfield>
      <subfield code="c">oldstorjrl</subfield>
    </datafield>
  </record>
</holding>
```

I need to change `datafield` @`ind1` to " " where @`tag="852`" AND no `subfield` with @`code="h"` exists. In this example, @`code="b"` and @`code="c"` exist, but @`code="h"` does not, so I'd want to modify this record.

I can think of ways to accomplish what I need using program logic, but can I use xmlstarlet directly to select the nodes I want based on the absence of a subnode?

Desired output from this record would be

```
<holding>
  <holding_id>2225031160001858</holding_id>
  <record>
    <leader>00210cx a22200085 454500</leader>
    <controlfield tag="001">h38165-01alliance_ohsu</controlfield>
    <controlfield tag="004">b10145746-01alliance_ohsu</controlfield>
    <controlfield tag="005">20200417125900.0</controlfield>
    <controlfield tag="008">2004170u\\\\0\\\0001aaund0999999</controlfield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="852">
      <subfield code="b">OHSUMAIN</subfield>
      <subfield code="c">oldstorjrl</subfield>
    </datafield>
  </record>
</holding>
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how I missed this, but it turned out to be straightforward

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '/holding/record/datafield[@tag="852"][not(subfield[@code="h"])]/@ind1' -v ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

This xpath expression should select the correct target node:

```
"//datafield[@ind1][not(subfield[@code="h"])]"
```

Comment: The datafields can have many tags as well as indicators so this will make undesirable changes